# Socksify and SSL for HTTPS request

Tags: ruby, sockets, ssl, socks

For a project I need to make an HTTPS call through a Socks5 proxy so I can access the remote API of a customer.
The original code I'm using is this:

```
url = "/proxyValidate?service=#{migration_station_verification_url}&ticket=#{service_ticket}"

if Rails.env == 'development'
  uri = URI.parse(soe_cas_url + url)
  Net::HTTP.SOCKSProxy('127.0.0.1', 1080).start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
    res = http.get(uri.path)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(res)
    doc.remove_namespaces!
    doc.xpath('//sessionId').first.content
  end
else
  http = Net::HTTP.new(soe_cas_url)
  http.use_ssl = true
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
  res = http.request(req)
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(res)
  doc.remove_namespaces!
  doc.xpath('//sessionId').first.content
end
```

The goal is to use the proxy only in development environment. When I make the call using the proxy I receive the error:

**wrong status line: "<!DOCTYPE**

Googling this shows I need to set the **use_ssl** flag to true, which works outside the development cycle. When using the socksify there is no such mechanism. If I call this inside the do block, I receive an error that the session is already started. Calling it outside the block returns an exception that no such function exists.

Anyone can tell me how to run SSL/HTTPS through the socksify proxy?

**EDIT:**

I'm currently playing around with pure sockets to get what I want, using the following code:

```
  socket = Socket::TCPSocket.open('127.0.0.1', 1080)

  ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
  ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  ssl_context.ca_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'ssl', 'cacert.pem')

  ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, ssl_context)
  ssl_socket.sync_close = true
  ssl_socket.connect

  request = "GET #{url} HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nHost: #{soe_cas_url}"
  ssl_socket.puts(request)
  ssl_socket.puts("")

  response = ""
  while (line = ssl_socket.gets)
    response << line
  end
```

This however fails at the **ssl_socket.connect** with the following error:

**ssl_connect syscall returned=5 errno=0 state=sslv2/v3 read server hello a**

I've tried using self-signed certificates, no certificates etc but nothing seems to work. I do know the endpoint relies on self-signed certificates on staging environmnet.

Comment: May I enquire as to why you're using a proxy in your development environment when you're not using it for production?

Comment: because the development environment is not part of the network where the production runs. Production is part of a network where the remote endpoint is reachable by just calling it. With the Socks connection I tunnel the traffic into the desired network to make the call.

Comment: I can't help you with that, sorry, but as an alternative you might consider mocking the external service.

Comment: can't do, cause I need to verify that the tunneling works as well..